# Custom font in iphone not being displayed properly

Tags: iphone, fonts

I installed a custom font called "modern no. 20" (already installed in my mac) into my iphone project .

I copied the modernno20.ttf into my resources.
Now in my app-info.plist i added this font name in "Fonts provided by application".

Then i added

```
   cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"modernno20.ttf" size:14.0];
```

in my tableviewcode .

i dont know why but this font is not properly displayed.is there any thing i missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call the font in your `fontWithName` call, the string should be the name of the font as it is displayed in the Mac's 'Font Book' app, and not the actual filename of the referenced font file.

Comment: in font book its displayed "Modern No. 20"  so i changed my code to [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Modern No. 20.ttf" size:14.0]]; it doesnt seem to work

Comment: In your Info.plist, the key UIAppFonts should contain the string of your font name like this: MyFont.ttf which is how the name of it is written in the Font Book app. When you go to create the font in your method file, the call will be [UIFont fontWithName: @"MyFont" size: 12.0] which is without the ttf extension.

Comment: ok that was the problem i were adding the .ttf extension in the code...thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

There hasn’t been an easy way to add custom fonts to your iPhone applications. As of iOS 4 it has become very easy to do. there could be  possibility you would have missed some of the step to get custom font work.
Here is what you need to do in order to add custom fonts,

Check  [How to include ttf fonts to iOS app](http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html)